# Delete rest of HTML file after some text

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am scraping HTML file using BeautifulSoup in python.
I want to delete text after find a word.

Ex:

```
<div class="content">

<p> Page 1 </p>
<p> Page 2 </p>
<p> Page 3 </p>
<p> Page 4 </p>
<p> Page 5 </p>

</div>
```

I want to delete from Page 3.

```
<div class="content">

<p> Page 1 </p>
<p> Page 2 </p>
<p> Page 3 </p>

</div>
```

I have tried the following

```
p = soup.findAll('p')
if len(p) > 3 :
   d = p[3]
   while d:
       e = d.next
       d.extract()
       d = e
```

replacing `d.extract()` with `del(d)` is also not working.
Please help.

Comment: Exactly how do you want to delete this? just that section? or everything down the rest of the page, including closing tags?

Comment: Rest of the html page, but I want to maintain the closing tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

> ```
> p = soup.findAll('p')  
> while len(p) > 3:
>     last_p = p.pop()
>     last_p.extract()
> ```